# Google play: required android version doesn't match manifest minSdk version

Tags: android, google-play

I published my app to beta in google play.

[image]

But in manifest specified another version:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
```

Anyone else encountered this problem? What could it be?

**Update:** I extracted the manifest from apk. minSdkVersion in it = 10.

[image]

May be it is a feature of beta testing?

**Update 2: After publishing app to production "Requires Android" changed to specified in manifest**

Comment: Have you ever tried installing it on a Donut device?

Comment: Have you tried to enter the beta testing group with a device running 1.6 ? and did you get offert the app? Reading to all this here, seems that there is a bug in publisher console. My first idea was also, are u using android studio, how many libs, how many manifests are merged, what das your gradle build files look etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only in alpha and beta testing. I had a similar issue. Later, after promoting it to production, it began showing correct sdk version. So it might be some bug in alpha and beta testing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Android Studio?

If that's the case, check your [`build.gradle`](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html#buildFileBasics) file. It also defines a `minSdkVersion` and overrides the one of your manifest:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    // ...

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19

        //...

    }

    //...

}
```

Comment: I'm using idea without gradle, but app builds with Jenkins build server

Answer (score 0):

The fact that *Size* and *Current Version* "vary with device" makes me think you have multiple active APKs. One that perhaps you initially uploaded that supports 1.6, and then the latest one which supports 2.3.3. Go the APKs section for your app in your android [dev/publishing console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish) and make sure you only have a single APK "in production".

Comment: My app is published to beta. Active is latest one apk, previous apk's have status unpublished. No apk's have published to production yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Android Studio you have to set build.gradle file.

Set your gradle in defaultConfig and retry:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    // ...

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.01"

    }

    //...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.add following inside application tag of AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

2. we can directly add the version code like

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4030500" />

  4030500 is version code which is stored inside google-play-services_lib>res>values>version.xml
```

Like

```
 <integer name="google_play_services_version">4030500</integer>
```

Conclusion: Latest google play services requires a version name, which is to be mentioned using  inside AndroidManifest.xml

Note: I would strongly recommend to use 1st way